# Варианты структуры MYSQL таблиц для сайта

Tags: mysql, wordpress, opencart, структуры

Хочется узнать про различные варианты формирование структуры таблиц для сайта, но не знаю по каким запросам искать. О чем идет речь: Например в вордпресс, все posttypesхранятся в одной таблице(wp_posts), а категории, рубрики, изображения и все поля в во второй (wp_postmeta). А в каком-нибудь opencart за каждый все отвечают разные таблицы, и мета теги категорий, в таблице для категорий(и то не основной), товаров в другой, юзеров в третей и т.д.
Какими терминами правильно обозначается эти варианты структуры чтобы можно было ознакомиться с плюсами, минусами и вообще всеми вариантами.
Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: *не знаю по каким запросам искать* Искать и читать по терминам "нормализация", "нормальные формы" и т.п. Плюс "проектирование БД", "Построение ER-диаграммы" и прочие базово-теоретические термины.

Comment: посмотрите такой термин как EAV